# When to call runResourceT on streaming-bytestring?

Tags: haskell, haskell-streaming

I am a Haskell beginner and still learning about monad transformers.

I am trying to use the [streaming-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring) library to read a binary file, process chunks of bytes, and print the result as each chunk is processed. I believe this is the popular `streaming` library that provides an alternative to lazy bytestrings. It appears the authors copy-pasted the [lazy bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) documentation and added some arbitrary examples.

The examples mention `runResourceT` without going into any discussion of what it is or how to use it. It appears that should use `runResourceT` on any streaming-bytestring function that performs an action. That's fine, but what if I'm reading an infinite stream that processes chunks and prints them? Should I call runResourceT every time I want to process the chunk?

My code is something like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming as BSS
import System.TimeIt

main = timeIt $ processByteChunks $ BSS.drop 100 $ BSS.readFile "filename"
```

and I'm unsure of how to organize `processByteChunks` as a recursive function that iterates through the binary file.

If I call `runResourceT` only once, it would read the infinite file BEFORE printing, right? That seems bad.

```
main = timeIt $ runResourceT $ processByteChunks $ BSS.drop 100 $ BSS.readFile "filename"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResourceT` monad just cleans up resources in a timely fashion when you're finished with them.  In this case, it will ensure the file handle opened by `BSS.readFile` is closed when the stream is consumed.  (Unless the stream truly is infinite, in which case I guess it won't.)

In your application, you only want to call it once, since you don't want the file closed until you've read all the chunks.  Don't worry -- it has nothing to do with the timing of output or anything like that.

Here's an example with a recursive `processByteChunks` that should work.  It will read lazily and generate output as chunks are lazily read:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming as BSS
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import System.TimeIt

main :: IO ()
main = timeIt $ runResourceT $
  processByteChunks $ BSS.drop 100 $ BSS.readFile "filename"

processByteChunks :: MonadIO m => BSS.ByteString m () -> m ()
processByteChunks = go 0 0
  where go len nulls stream = do
          m <- BSS.unconsChunk stream
          case m of
            Just (bs, stream') -> do
              let len' = len + BS.length bs
                  nulls' = nulls + BS.length (BS.filter (==0) bs)
              liftIO $ print $ "cumulative length=" ++ show len'
                                      ++ ", nulls=" ++ show nulls'
              go len' nulls' stream'
            Nothing -> return ()
```